# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Modal controller still working when modalInstance is closed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with AngularJS and UI Bootstrap

I open a modal for the user login.
It works fine, but the problem is when I try to return to the first page.
Seems like when the modal is closed, but the controller ('LoginInstanceCtrl') is still there and is listening for the event '$routeChangeSuccess'. So the modal doesn't exist now and I get an error.

```
.controller('LoginInstanceCtrl', ['$modalInstance', '$scope', function($modalInstance, $scope) {
  //do stuff
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function ($event, current) {
    $modalInstance.close();
  });
}])
```

Thanks

Edit

Here I put a link to the full code, the only difference with the real code is that in the modal I have an iFrame and the routing to the "second page" is made there.

https://github.com/agusgambina/angularModalError

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post your full code please.

Comment: @Jayram thank you for your reply. I reproduced the error and I posted the code.